# Renaming spark output csv in azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-storage

I have a Databricks notebook setup that works as the following;

- pyspark connection details to Blob storage account
- Read file through spark dataframe
- convert to pandas Df
- data modelling on pandas Df
- convert to spark Df
- write to blob storage in single file

My problem is, that you can not name the file output file, where I need a static csv filename.

Is there way to rename this in pyspark?

```
## Blob Storage account information
storage_account_name = ""
storage_account_access_key = ""

## File location and File type
file_location = "path/.blob.core.windows.net/Databricks_Files/input"
file_location_new = "path/.blob.core.windows.net/Databricks_Files/out"
file_type = "csv"

## Connection string to connect to blob storage
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
  storage_account_access_key)
```

Followed by outputting file after data transformation

```
dfspark.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
  .mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(file_location_new)
```

Where the file is then write as **"part-00000-tid-336943946930983.....csv"**

Where as a the goal is to have **"Output.csv"**

Another approach I looked at was just recreating this in python but have not come across in the documentation yet of how to output the file back to blob storage.

I know the method to retrieve from Blob storage is *.get_blob_to_path* via [microsoft.docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/explore-data-blob#blob-dataexploration)

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: see if that works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/75579796/680074

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hadoop/Spark will parallel output the compute result per partition into one file, so you will see many `part-<number>-....` files in a HDFS output path like `Output/` named by you.

If you want to output all results of a computing into one file, you can merge them via the command `hadoop fs -getmerge /output1/part* /output2/Output.csv` or set the number of reduce processes with `1` like using `coalesce(1)` function.

So in your scenario, you only need to adjust the order of calling these functions to make the `coalease` function called at the front of `save` function, as below.

```
dfspark.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
  .mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").coalesce(1).save(file_location_new)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `coalesce` and `repartition` do not help with saving the dataframe into 1 normally named file.

I ended up just renaming the 1 csv file and deleting the folder with log:

```
def save_csv(df, location, filename):
  outputPath = os.path.join(location, filename + '_temp.csv')

  df.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite").options(header="true", inferSchema="true").option("delimiter", "\t").save(outputPath)

  csv_files = os.listdir(os.path.join('/dbfs', outputPath))

  # moving the parquet-like temp csv file into normally named one
  for file in csv_files:
    if file[-4:] == '.csv':
      dbutils.fs.mv(os.path.join(outputPath,file) , os.path.join(location, filename))
      dbutils.fs.rm(outputPath, True)

# using save_csv
save_csv_location = 'mnt/.....'
save_csv(df, save_csv_location, 'name.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mssparkutils to rename the file

```
old_name = f"path/.blob.core.windows.net/Databricks_Files/out"
new_name = f"path/.blob.core.windows.net/Databricks_Files/out/output.csv"
mssparkutils.fs.mv(old_name,new_name)
```

Just in case: If your file is autogenerated and you are getting the filenames as `part-0000*` files, then use python to fetch the part filename alone and then use the above code to rename it.