# Pyspark- Save each dataframe to a single file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to save filtered dataframe back to the same source file.

I wrote below code to transform the content of each file in a directory to separate Dataframe, filter it and save it back to the same file

```
rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("/content/sample_data/test_data")
# collect the RDD to a list
list_elements = rdd.collect()
for element in list_elements:
  path, data = element
  df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([data]))
  df = df.filter('d != 721')
  df.write.save(path, format="json", mode="overwrite")
```

I was expecting that it will overwrite the file with the updated data, but it is creating a folder with the file name and creating below structure and part files:

[image]

How can I save each updated dataframe back to the same source file(.txt)?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To save it to 1 file use `.coalesce(1)` or `.repartition(1)` option before `.save()`, that will result in the same folder-like structure, but there will be 1 json file inside.

To save it with a „normal” name after saving it you’d need to cut the 1 json file inside, paste and rename it with desired name. You can see code how it could look like for csv files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649039/renaming-spark-output-csv-in-azure-blob-storage/61929131#61929131)